# Typescript {Key: Value} Pair of an Array of Types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

So, I'm getting an undefined error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Flavor' of undefined
```

I have a type, Flavor:

```
interface Flavor {
  flavorId: string;
  name: string;
}
```

I'm getting graphql my query back in this format:

```
  "data": {
    "Flavor": [
      {
        "flavorId": "a42a313e-d40d-4a01-a4cd-7e457eb65468",
        "name": "Morning Breath"
      },
      {
        "flavorId": "c048e795-5a51-4708-ac49-b9db83ce3033",
        "name": "Fart"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried many things I've found on SO. But currently, I am using this state, where I am trying to store my query results as an array of Flavor Types:

```
const [flavorsList, setFlavorsList] = React.useState<Flavor[]>()

React.useEffect(() => {
    setFlavorsList(data.Flavor);
  }, [data])
```

Do I solve this using an indexable type? Not sure what I'm doing, if it's not obvious.

Comment: replace data.Flavor with data?.Flavor

Comment: Amazing. Not sure what that did but it worked. Thank you @psycho11

Comment: It’s the optional chaining operator.  It means that if data is undefined the expression data.Flavor will evaluate to undefined. So just understand that it is now possible your state will get set to undefined.